# How to look for the specific index of an array once i enter the mortgage id number in twilio function?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

This is my code in twilio functions,

```
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
 const got = require('got');
 
    const mortgageInfo = event.mortgageInfo;
     const mortgage_number = event.mortgage_number;

 
 
 
 got('https://cyan-sparrow-7490.twil.io/assets/data6.json').then (response =>{
     
     
     const mort = JSON.parse(response.body);
     
     let mortgageData = mort;
     
     
     //Begin filter code
    let val = mortgageInfo;
  
     // I think this line here is my problem
  
     let index = mortgageData.map(function(e) { return e.mortgageid.value; }).indexOf(val);
    
     // I think this line here is my problem


     //End filter code
     
     let mortgageSpecificData = mortgageData[index];
     
     
  
    callback(null,mortgageSpecificData);
     
     
 });
```

===========SAMPLE ASSET ==============

[image]

===========SAMPLE ASSET ==============

Comment: Sorry about that, I already edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be a lot simpler than that. One thing to note is that `event.mortgageInfo` is going to be a string, but in your data, the `mortgageid` property is a number. So when you compare, you need to convert first.

Here's a function that I believe will work:

```js
const got = require("got");

exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
  const mortgageInfo = parseInt(event.mortgageInfo, 10);

  got("https://cyan-sparrow-7490.twil.io/assets/data6.json").then(
    (response) => {
      const mortgageData = JSON.parse(response.body);

      const mortgageSpecificData = mortgageData.find(
        (mortgage) => mortgage.mortgageid === mortgageInfo
      );

      callback(null, mortgageSpecificData);
    }
  );
};
```

In this case I first change the `mortgageInfo` into a number by calling [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) on the `event.mortgageInfo`. Then, once you fetch the data and parse it, you can find the object with the matching `mortgageid` using the [array's `find` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). `find` takes a function that is called with each member of the array and returns when it evaluates to `true`. In this case, for each member of the array we check whether the `mortgageid` matches the `mortgageInfo` we got earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const index = mortgageData.findIndex((e) => e.mortgagid === mortgagid)
```

Comment: Hi Alan, It didn't work, it, I also tried to correct it with mortgageid still, it says mortgageid is not define.